# how to get a native GDI bitmap from a .net bitmap

Tags: c++, .net, gdi+, gdi

i would like to use a .net Bitmap in a native library using Pinvoke Technology, the native function has the following prototype ,

```
int cropImage(  bool aBlocking,Gdiplus::Bitmap *aInputImage, )
```

I worte the following pinvoke

```
public extern int cropImage( bool blocking , Intptr bitmap )
```

and I am calling it like this

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap b = new Syste.Drawing.Bitmap("Amour.jpg");
cropImage(true,b.getHitmap());
```

but it is not working , what do you suggest ?

Answer (score 3):

Gdiplus::Bitmap is a C++ class, it is declared in the `<GdiPlusHeaders.h>` Windows SDK header file.  It is a wrapper class to make the rather unfriendly low-level GDI+ C interface easier to use.  System.Drawing.Bitmap is **not** a direct substitute for this C++ class, it is also a wrapper class around the low-level GDI+ api but written in C#.  It has no relationship at all with the C++ wrapper.  Using the HBITMAP you get from Bitmap.GetHbitmap() will not work either, that's a *handle*, not a C++ object.

You cannot call this function directly from C#, pinvoke does not support creating C++ objects.  You will need to write a *ref class* wrapper in the C++/CLI language.  A language that supports both writing managed code and calling native C++ code without pinvoke.  And you can `#include <gdiplus.h>` as necessary so you can create the Gdiplus::Bitmap object.  Another approach is to create a DLL using C++ that has two exported functions, one that creates a Gdiplus::Bitmap and another that destroys it.  That will let you use pinvoke, declaring the argument as IntPtr instead.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that the best way to overcome this problem is to use a native library which accept a HBitmap and then use CBitmap::fromHandle function and then call the api you are trying to communicate with !